# version mismatched of firebase @angular/fire@16.0.0

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, angularfire

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: firebase-angular-crud@0.0.0 npm ERR! Found:
> @angular/common@16.2.12 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common npm ERR!
> @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from the root project npm ERR!   peer
> @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from @angular/fire@16.0.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/fire npm ERR!     @angular/fire@"^16.0.0" from
> the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm
> ERR! @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from the root project npm ERR!  npm
> ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@17.0.4 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/core npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.0.4" from
> @angular/common@17.0.4 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common npm
> ERR!     @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from the root project npm ERR!  npm
> ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm
> ERR! npm ERR! For a full report see: npm ERR! C:\Users\NAFIS
> LIGARI\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-22T06_43_54_156Z-eresolve-report.txt
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\NAFIS
> LIGARI\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-22T06_43_54_156Z-debug-0.log

i have added latest version by this command : `npm install @angular/fire` and `npm add @angular/fire`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.